# observing objects in factory - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

In a factory I have this:

```
$http.get('/api/whatever').success(function(data) {
  result = data.obj
});
```

In the controller I can't observe any change. But shouldn't I, if I use a reference to `result` like:

```
angular.module('aModule')
  .controller('TheCtrl', function ($scope, MyFactory) {      
    $scope.ifOnly = MyFactory.result;
  });
```

In contrast if I do for example:

```
 $http.get('/api/whatever').success(function(data) {
   result.foo = 'foo';
   result.bar = 'bar';
 });
```

The object in the controller gets the change.

The question is, shouln't the reference be noticed, but a change of a value not?

EDIT:

In the controller I tried:

```
 $scope.$watch('MyFactory.result', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log('changed');
    console.log(oldVal);
    console.log(newVal);
}, true);
```

The log is:

```
changed
undefined
undefined
```

..as the final answer.
I just don't believe that copying the object value by value is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

References to be replaced，you can try this:

result.obj = data.obj;

```
$scope.ifOnly = MyFactory.result.obj;
```

Comment: no, its the same issue. I just dont understand why a reference doesn't get noticed, while a changed value is.

Comment: "result" have new address after result = data.obj

Comment: yes, I see. I guess you are right. But your recommendation leads to the same bad result anyway :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
//factory
getWhatever(){
  return $http.get('/api/whatever');
}

//controller
angular.module('aModule')
  .controller('TheCtrl', function ($scope, MyFactory) {      
    MyFactory.getWhatever().then(function(data){
       $scope.ifOnly = data;
    });
  });
```